# How to hide image automatically if no link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the footer of a website I have 5 social icons. They are just standard images. Of course wrapped round each one is `<a href=""></a>`.

Basically, I need some code that would hide an icon if it is not linked to anywhere. Essentially, 'if no link, hide image' sort of statement.

Would anyone know if this is possible?

---

Problem solved with CSS as per answer below. Thanks guys!

Comment: What do you exactly mean with _not linked to anywhere_? Can you provide some code as an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with pure CSS:

```
a[href=""] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Does image has `href` attribute?

Comment: @Satpal my apologies. I saw "images" and then the example he had given and merged the too. Sometimes my hands work faster than my brain. Thank you for pointing out the mistake, I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try Jquery :-

```
$('a[href=""]').hide();
```

Or simply use CSS for this purpose :-

```
a[href=""] {
   display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could do it in jQuery

```
$("a[href='']").hide();
```

This will hide the image as well, since it is the parent of it.

Or in css:

```
a[href=''] img {  /*  this selector matches images inside <a href=''> */
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code in javascript code using jquery

```
$('a[href=""]').hide();
```